# Kofax TotalAgility Databalase joining to TotalAgilityDocuments Database

Tags: kofax

I have to analyze the Confidence levels per Job/Document/Field for "KOFAX Total Agility". I need to pull data from the Jobs, JobHistory tables of the [TotalAgility] database down to the Documents and Field tables of the [TotalAgilityDocuments] database. This is for requested analysis.

There's a doc on some of the TotalAgility tables but I can't find anything else on the other KOFAX TotalAgility included Databases.

I'm looking for the join information or ideally an ERD on the two databases for Kofax TotalAgility.

Thanks! Bob

Comment: This is something that Kofax Analytics for TotalAgility (KAFTA) should deliver out of the box: https://www.kofax.com/Products/process-intelligence/analytics-for-totalagility

Comment: Thank you @WolfgangRadl,  Unfortunately, I have to consolidate reporting using PowerBI and upper management decided that product wouldn't be 'viable'. <sigh> l

Comment: hey Bob, did you find a way to do that?

Comment: Not a performant way...  :/                                                                            From TotalAgility.[dbo].JOB (NOLOCK) fj 
JOIN TotalAgility.[dbo].VARIABLE (NOLOCK) fjv ON fj.JOB_ID = fjv.OWNER_ID
JOIN TotalAgility_Documents.[dbo].Document (NOLOCK) Exported on ParentId = CAST( fjv.VAR_VALUE as xml).value( '(FolderVariableValue/InstanceId)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  <br> the xml call is the most expensive.